# Netflix won't install on Apple TV 4

Tags: appletv, netflix

Netflix won't install on my new Apple TV 4.
Other apps install fine. My iTunes account is working.
Netflix goes from "Install" to spinner and back to "Install" again.
Other apps go to "Open" after spinner. Ideas?
Location is Sweden. Netflix is readily available here and I had no trouble on my Apple TV 3.
Network is 100 Mbit and working fine.
No errors are reported.